# Two friends playing with a coin

Tags: probability

Two friends $A,B$ are playing a game, with these statements:

- They will flip a coin six times.
- If the sequence of flips is either $6$ heads or $6$ tails, then player $A$ will pay $\$310$ to player $B$.
- In any other case, player $B$ will pay $\$10$ to player $A$.

Let's assume they will play again a lot of times.

The questions are:

- In the long term, who is going to lose money with this?
- How does the outcome differ as the number of flips increases? (i.e. with $100$ flips, or a billion)

Thanks very much, any help will be more than welcome!

EDIT: my approach (wich I think absolutely wrong) was this:

-Total combinations in 6 coin flips: 2^6=64

-Probability of having 6 equal flips (player B wins): 2/64=0.03125 (3,125%)

-probability of NOT having 6 equal flips: 100-3,125=96,875%

-With this results, in 100 flips player A will win 96,8*10=968 dollars, and player B 3,2*310=992.

Comment: Try to calculate the expected value of bucks A gained.

Comment: Since this is not a 'do my homework for free' service, another question that arises is, what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks everybody for your fast responses. I think my approach was absolutely wrong:

Comment: @JannikPitt, I think you mean 1296-(2*10)=1276, dont' you? Or maybe the result is 12940?

Comment: @Jannik Pitt, thanks a lot for your help, but...are you sure that figures are right? 1/18 seems to be incorrect as the result of the first operation...

Comment: You're almost there, except for some mistakes in copying numbers.  I prefer using fractions, but using percentages are fine.  Calculate the expected gain of player $A$.  $$0.96875 \times (-10) + 0.03125 \times 310 = -9.6875 + 9.6875 = 0$$  Therefore, it's a fair game: in the long run, both players $A$ and $B$ will gain nothing.

Comment: Ok @GNUSupporter, thanks very much foryour help!